# Badge numbers of usernames with long names in badge page appear cut off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

A freehand red circle points to the problem.

Browser is Firefox 3.6.

> [image: screenshot of the "Electorate" badge page]

Comment: OMG __FREEHAND CIRCLE__

Comment: I'm glad that my previous request for freehand circles didn't go unnoticed.

Comment: Confirmed in IE8.

Comment: Doesn't happen in Safari.

Comment: [Link to page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/155/electorate). Confirmed in Chrome 8/Win and Safari 5.0.3/Win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, there's a maximum width we can fit in there (3 columns as I recall) and not have it overflow the page.

Comment: Right, too bad the cut is so crude but I'd say beautifying it should be a pretty low priority.